# Problema con postlink en cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

soy novato con cakephp y estoy creando un form para agregar, editar y eliminar registros.
El problema es que intento que el link de eliminar se vea como un botón, lo he logrado con css , creando una clase button a la cual le di un estilo . El tema es que no entiendo 2 cosas :

1) Que diferencia hay entre link y postlink ?
2) Si le aplico la clase button a postlink la ignora, como puedo aplicarle el estilo de la clase button ?

Copio el código :

```html
<h1>Listado de Usuarios</h1>
<p><?php echo $this->Html->link("Agrega Nuevo", array('action' => 'add')); ?></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nombres</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Sector</th>
        <th>Teléfonos</th>
        <th>@mail</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($registros as $registros):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $registros ['Maestro']['id'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros ['Maestro']['nombre'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros ['Maestro']['apellido'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros ['Maestro']['sector'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros ['Maestro']['tele'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $registros ['Maestro']['email'];?></td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link("Editar", array('controller' => 'maestros', 'action'=>'editar', $registros['Maestro']['id']), array('class' => 'button')); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->postlink('Eliminar', array('action' => 'eliminar', $registros['Maestro']['id']), array('confirm'=>'Eliminar a ' . $registros['Maestro']['id']), array('class' => 'button')); ?>
            </td>    
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Como decía, en el echo que lleva a 'editar' , toma el estilo 'button' perfectamente, en el que lleva a 'Eliminar' , lo ignora ...
Agradeceré cualquier ayuda !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estos son los parametros que espera recibir el helper

```
FormHelper::postLink(string $title, mixed $url = null, array $options = array ())
```

Por lo que la clase la tienes que meter dentro de opciones quedando asi:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postlink('Eliminar', array('action' => 'eliminar', $registros['Maestro']['id']), array('confirm'=>'Eliminar a ' . $registros['Maestro']['id'], 'class' => 'button')); ?>
```

Aqui tienes mas info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::postLink

Comment: Genial !!! Gracias !

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de `link` es simplemente un enlace a una url externa, como un `<a href="url"></a>`, cuando lleva `http` la toma como externa y cuando no busca dentro del dominio.

En el caso de `postlink` se crea un formulario con `GET` o `POST` dependiendo de la configuración que tu le des.